# Getting only records not in second table LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

i need help figuring out how to do this, i have a DataSet that contains records by Date and currencyCode, what i want is to compare two datasets and know if one (left table) have records that don´t exists on the second one (right table), i have the following code for joining the table based on date and code:

```
vLINQ = (From ContentExchangeRates In myDataset.Tables(0).AsEnumerable() _
         Join PartnerExchangeRates In PartnerDataSet.Tables(0).AsEnumerable() _
         On ContentExchangeRates.Field(Of Date)("EffectiveDate") Equals PartnerExchangeRates.Field(Of Date)("RateDate") _
         And ContentExchangeRates.Field(Of String)("CurrencyCode") Equals PartnerExchangeRates.Field(Of Date)("CurrencyCode") _
         Select New With { .PartnerRateDate = PartnerExchangeRates.Field(Of Date)("RateDate"), _ etc}).ToList
```

Using Jeff answer the code looks like this:

```
vLINQ = (From ContentExchangeRates In myDataSet.Tables(0).AsEnumerable() _
                                Group Join PartnerExchangeRates In PartnerDataSet.Tables(0).AsEnumerable() _
                                On PartnerExchangeRates.Field(Of Date)("RateDate") Equals ContentExchangeRates.Field(Of Date)("EffectiveDate") _
                                And PartnerExchangeRates.Field(Of String)("CurrencyCode") Equals ContentExchangeRates.Field(Of String)("ConvertCurrencyCode") _
                                Into result = Group From m In result.DefaultIfEmpty _
                                                    Select New With _
                                                    { _
                                                    .PartnerRateDate = m.Field(Of Date)("RateDate") _
                                                    }).ToList
```

But i get the following error: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: row

I want to be able to make a left outer join, that will only retrieve records that do not exists on PartnerExchangeRates table, but i don´t know what to do any more :(

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To perform a left outer join, you need to do a group join and go through the results of the group join and use `DefaultIfEmpty`.  It will translate to a left outer join.

```
Dim query =
    From cer In myDataset.Tables(0).AsEnumerable
    Group Join per In PartnerDataSet.Tables(0).AsEnumerable
        On New With
        {
            .Date = cer.Field(Of Date)("EffectiveDate"),
            .Currency = cer.Field(Of String)("CurrencyCode")
        }
        Equals New With
        {
            .Date = per.Field(Of Date)("RateDate"),
            .Currency = per.Field(Of String)("CurrencyCode")
        }
        Into pers = Group
    From per in pers.DefaultIfEmpty
    Where per Is Nothing
    Select PartnerRateDate = per.Field(Of Date)("RateDate"), ...
```

Comment: Im getting the following error: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: row

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Enumerable.Except(IEnumerable, IEnumerable, IEqualityComparer)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
Option Infer On

Module Module1

    Class RowComparer : Implements IEqualityComparer(Of DataRow)

        Public Function Equals1(x As DataRow, y As DataRow) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of DataRow).Equals
            ' use .Equals for the DateTime and Is for the String
            Return x(0).Equals(y(0)) AndAlso x(1) Is y(1)
        End Function

        Public Function GetHashCode1(obj As DataRow) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of DataRow).GetHashCode
            Return obj(0).GetHashCode Xor obj(1).GetHashCode
        End Function

    End Class

    Sub ShowDt(dt As DataTable)
        For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Console.WriteLine(CDate(r(0)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & " " & CStr(r(1)))
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("-------------")

    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim dt(1) As DataTable
        For i = 0 To 1
            dt(i) = New DataTable
            dt(i).Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "EffectiveDate", .DataType = Type.GetType("System.DateTime")})
            dt(i).Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "CurrencyCode", .DataType = Type.GetType("System.String")})
        Next

        ' test data
        For i = 0 To 1
            For j = 1 To 10
                Dim nr = dt(i).NewRow
                nr("EffectiveDate") = New DateTime(2015, 1, j)
                nr("CurrencyCode") = "USD"
                dt(i).Rows.Add(nr)
            Next
        Next

        ' remove a couple of rows from the second table
        dt(1).Rows.RemoveAt(9)
        dt(1).Rows.RemoveAt(2)

        ShowDt(dt(0))
        ShowDt(dt(1))

        ' find the rows in dt(0) which are not in dt(1)...
        Dim missings = (dt(0).AsEnumerable.Except(dt(1).AsEnumerable, New RowComparer())).CopyToDataTable()

        ShowDt(missings)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

But if it happens that your data is amenable to being stored in lists, your code could be cleaner and more readable:

```
Option Infer On

Module Module1

    Public Class DateAndCurrency
        Public Property EffectiveDate As DateTime
        Public Property CurrencyCode As String

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return Me.EffectiveDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & " " & Me.CurrencyCode
        End Function

    End Class

    Public Class DateAndCurrencyComparer : Implements IEqualityComparer(Of DateAndCurrency)

        Public Function Equals1(x As DateAndCurrency, y As DateAndCurrency) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of DateAndCurrency).Equals
            Return x.CurrencyCode = y.CurrencyCode AndAlso x.EffectiveDate = y.EffectiveDate
        End Function

        Public Function GetHashCode1(obj As DateAndCurrency) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of DateAndCurrency).GetHashCode
            Return obj.CurrencyCode.GetHashCode Xor obj.EffectiveDate.GetHashCode
        End Function

    End Class

    Sub Main()

        ' test data
        Dim daccs As New List(Of List(Of DateAndCurrency))
        For i = 0 To 1
            Dim dacc As New List(Of DateAndCurrency)
            For j = 1 To 10
                dacc.Add(New DateAndCurrency With {.EffectiveDate = New DateTime(2015, 1, j), .CurrencyCode = "USD"})
            Next
            daccs.Add(dacc)
        Next

        ' remove a couple of rows from the second list
        daccs(1).RemoveAt(9)
        daccs(1).RemoveAt(2)

        For i = 0 To 1
            daccs(i).ForEach(Sub(x) Console.WriteLine(x.ToString()))
            Console.WriteLine("-------------")
        Next

        ' find the items in daccs(0) which are not in daccs(1)...
        Dim missings = daccs(0).Except(daccs(1), New DateAndCurrencyComparer())

        missings.ToList().ForEach(Sub(x) Console.WriteLine(x.ToString()))
        Console.WriteLine("-------------")

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```